# Xamarin.Forms Picker ItemsSource stays empty in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

My picker stays empty. I already created a test list to test it in particular but it doesn't work either.

this is my XAML

```
<Picker x:Name="picker1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding AdditionSort}"/>
```

this is my code behind

```
List<AdditionSort> TestList
{
    get => testList;
    set => SetValue(ref testList, value);
}

List<AdditionSort> testList = new List<AdditionSort>();

void LoadList()
{
    TestList.Add(new AdditionSort { Name = "test1" });
    TestList.Add(new AdditionSort { Name = "test2" });
}
```

when I'm debugging I can see that my list is correct.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of List

Comment: Doesn't work. Already tried.

Comment: Did you try adding items at initiailizing of the List?

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean? In ctor?

Comment: Not in constructor but during initialization of testList. Line above `void LoadList()`

Comment: Use `public` access specifier before `List<AdditionSort> TestList`. It would work. But you must change it to `ObservableCollection` too or add items while initialising.

Answer (score 2):

1)Use `System.Generics.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

`ObservableCollection` notifies View on CollectionChanges where as List doesnot do that.

**(Or)**

2) Add items to List at initialization of List

```cs
List<AdditionSort> testList = new List<AdditionSort>()
{
    new AdditionSort(),
    new AdditionSort(),
    new AdditionSort(),
    new AdditionSort(),
}
```

Comment: No! Oh man, why? Is it because I open this page with a object in the ctor?

Comment: Where are you setting the BindingContext?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo to make the binding work and you can check the code:

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myModel m = new myModel();

        BindingContext = m;
    }
}

public class myModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    List<AdditionSort> testList = new List<AdditionSort>();

    public List<AdditionSort> TestList
    {
        get { return testList; }
        set
        {
            testList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public myModel() {

        LoadList();

    }

    void LoadList()
    {
        TestList.Add(new AdditionSort { Name = "test1" });
        TestList.Add(new AdditionSort { Name = "test2" });
    }
}

public class AdditionSort
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Picker x:Name="picker1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding AdditionSort}"/>

</StackLayout>
```

I uploaded my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Picker-binding).

Also, here is the document: [Setting a Picker's ItemsSource Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#responding-to-item-selection)